# QT C++ tmainCRTStartup exception

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm building a real-time graphing multithreaded QT C++ application using qcustomplot.h that uses signals and slots for various updates to the graphs. Additionally, OpenCV is being used in the main processing thread to generate the data.

It seems like I'm encountering some strange concurrency issues; At various times while running the program (sometimes relatively early, sometimes not until over 10 minutes of running), I get an exception that I can't get much out of.

Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEDCD7FA8C (Qt5Gui.dll) in VitalsOneProj.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000000002B8.

The stacktrace points to tmainCRTStartup() and then buries deep into Qt5Widgets.dll and Qt5Gui.dll

I have encountered this error with varying frequency throughout development. I have boost mutexes in both the qt mainwindow as well as in the adapter connecting the processing to the GUI. Adding the latter mutexes seemed to decrease the frequency, but the exceptions still occur. I feel that the exception may be coming from QT making an asynchronous call which then releases its lock and allows another call to collide and corrupt memory.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Solution: I fixed it by no longer releasing locks in functions that called replot(). Since replot() is asynchronous, collisions can occur in future GUI calls. I moved the unlocking of my mutexes to the afterReplot callback function to avoid these collisions and I no longer get an exception.

Comment: Why are you not using QMutex instead of boost's mutex in a Qt application? Either, could you please share your code?

Comment: The GUI code: https://github.com/TLadd/SeniorDesign/blob/master/VitalsOneProj/VitalsOneProj/GUI/mainwindow.cpp   and the adapter: https://github.com/TLadd/SeniorDesign/blob/master/VitalsOneProj/VitalsOneProj/Model/ViewAdapter.cpp 

I had already been using boost in other parts of my application, so I just went with those mutexes. Would it matter?

Comment: It is too long. Can you provide a minimal test case?

Comment: I've been trying to reduce the problem down myself. I've determined that if I create a thread that uses the viewAdapter to call 

view->AddHeartPoint(rand());
view->setHeartRate(rand());

repeatedly, I get the same exception

Comment: If I do any of the plot or set calls in QT in quick succession, it triggers the exception.

Comment: Calls to Qt GUI calls can only occur from the main thread. Maybe that has something to do with it, but without code I'm just guessing anyway. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread